# Automatically clear floats on last of type

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a simple grid using floats. However, I would like to automatically clear them after the last div.

http://jsfiddle.net/62mfJ/2/

```
.col50 {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: grey;
    font-size: 150%;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.col:last-of-type:after { // this does not work!
    content:'';
    display:block;
    clear: both;
}
```

HTML

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit dolores autem provident ea explicabo amet sequi tempora ducimus vitae fugit. Iure blanditiis magni possimus aperiam consectetur architecto laboriosam veniam perspiciatis.</p>
<div class="col50">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</div>
<div class="col50">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</div>
<div class="col50">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250">
</div>
<div class="col50">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x100">
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa commodi at ullam quae necessitatibus assumenda architecto veritatis aspernatur blanditiis amet ipsum velit totam provident earum adipisci ad corporis odio alias.</p>
```

For some reason this does not work:

```
.col:last-of-type:after { 
    content:'';
    display:block;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Not a single up vote all around? that's disappointing.

Comment: One for each, nice and fair.

Comment: Did none of these answers resolve the issue you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the `clear` on the `p` tag:

```
p {
  clear:both;
}
```

Also [`last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3alast-of-type) just refers to tags not classnames.

*Edit*

The way you are trying to clear is wrong... The `:after` element is inside the element itself but after his content not just "after" that then you can't clear with this trick. You may need a "wrapper" to apply this kind of clearfix.

Comment: Thanks, but sometimes the content may vary (such as an iframe, a different image, etc). Would the above be possible?

Comment: Does 'nth-type' also refer to tags, not classnames?

Comment: @tmyie the way you are trying to clear is wrong... The `:after` element is inside the element itself but after his content not just "after" that then you can't clear with this trick. You may need a "wrapper" to apply this kind of clearfix.

Comment: @tmyie the best you can do is `.col50 + *:not(.col50) {clear:both}` but :not hasn't enough support.

Answer (score 0):

You could put a wrapper around all of your columns and set the `overflow: auto;` style. This will force the browser to make the wrapper height match the floats inside and maintain the flow.

Here's an updated fiddle illustrating.

http://jsfiddle.net/62mfJ/3/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a good idea define grid and expect that after grid column should follows some another element. If you don't :last-of-type is not necessary.

Anyway you need define wrapper around columns because `:before` and `:after` CSS pseudo classes represents pseudo-element inside the element where it is defined. It means if you wrote CSS like this

```
.col:last-of-type:after { 
    content:'';
    display:block;
    clear: both;
}
```

Your HTML document is like this

```
<div class="col">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</div>
<div class="col">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</div>
<div class="col">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250">
</div>
<div class="col"> <!-- = :last-of-type -->
    :before
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x100">
    :after <!-- this clear has no effect when .col is floated -->
</div>
<!-- You have to clear HERE -->
```

Answer (score 0):

## How to clear floats efficiently using minimal code

I have been doing float clearing for a long time now I have used many methods some better than other. I have found the most efficient way to be the following:

Create a universal css class rule to clear floats.
(Add this to the bottom of your stylesheet for specificity).

```
.CF:before,
.CF:after{content:"";display:table;}
.CF:after{clear:both;}
```

Apply the class .CF to the containing element to be cleared.

In the case of your example a wrapping div.

```
<div class="CF">
  <div class="FloatedContent"></div>
  <div class="FloatedContent"></div>
</div>

<div class="UnfloatedContent"></div>
```

I've updated your fiddle to demonstrate.

http://jsfiddle.net/62mfJ/5/

*Doing float clearing this way means you can reuse and apply the class CF as many times as you desire resulting in a fast and efficient clearing system with minimal code.*

Comment: Why you need the `:before` element?

Comment: :before is only necessary when using 'table' rather than 'block'. It is not essential but helps to contain the top-margins of child elements in some browsers that misbehave.

Answer (score 0):

If you use:

```
.col50 + p {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    clear: both;
}
```

Instead of:

```
.col:last-of-type:after { 
    content:'';
    display:block;
    clear: both;
}
```

This will always clear the p element after every div with the class "col50".

Comment: 1. First you don't need content or display property. 2.The problem here is what about if another element that isn't `p` is after the last col50.

Answer (score 0):

Should it not be class 'col50'?  I don't see a class 'col'.

Here is my [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/csrow/L98Yk/)  This will clear anything that follows the last div.

```
    .col50:last-of-type + * {
        clear: both;
}
```

---

addition edit

Okay, try [this new answer.](http://jsfiddle.net/csrow/L98Yk/2/)

```
.col50:nth-last-of-type(1) + * ,
.col50:nth-last-of-type(2) + * 
{
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: AS you said clear after the last `div` http://jsfiddle.net/L98Yk/1/ not the last div with class `col50`